# Will an SSL without an Intermediate Certificate Cause a Signed APK to not load external CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova, ssl

I have an Android App (Cordova) that will not load externally referenced JS/CSS files, even though they are being served over https. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://app.winetracker.co/dist/application.min.20171213v2.css">
<script src="https://app.winetracker.co/dist/thirdparties.min.20171213v2.js"></script>
<script src="https://app.winetracker.co/dist/application.min.20171213v2.js"></script>
```

I ran a test against my SSL cert and got the result that it is missing an intermediate certificate:
[image]

Would this be the reason why the signed APK would NOT load the js and css files? (They work fine when I run the app locally on my android device or virtual simulators)

Comment: Also, the production version of the app on iOS loads everything fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!
It turns out that it was the exact reason why the Release version of the APK wouldn't load the external JS and CSS files. All it good now. Just had to re-configure/install my certs properly on the server.

Comment: The intermediate certificates are essential to build the trust chain which means they are essential for successful https. Desktop browser might use caching and other tricks to work around broken servers which don't provide the missing certificate but you cannot rely on this.